# A formal grammar for P?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fl.formal-languages, grammars

Let $P$ be the class of formal languages that have polynomial-time decider, i.e. for each $L\in P$ there exists a Turing-machine $T$ such that for each $w\in L$ machine $T$ decides if $w\in L$ in polynomial time wrt the length of $w$.

Is it possible to define a grammar (in any "reasonable" sense) that could be used to define exactly the languages in $P$?

Comment: Not sure about a grammar, but we know that P is equivalent to languages expressible using first order logic + a fixed point operator and ordering.

Comment: Check http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12/correspondence-between-complexity-classes-and-logic, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/869/is-there-a-logic-without-induction-that-captures-much-of-p, and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/is-there-a-natural-restriction-of-vo-logic-which-captures-p-or-np.

Comment: A related question asks about programming languages that implement P: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/programming-languages-for-efficient-computation

Some of those answer might be relevant

Comment: "Is it possible to define *a grammar* (in any "reasonable" sense) that could be used to define exactly the languages in  ?" I think you are using "grammar" not in their standard meaning in the literature. I think the question is not clear, I can't see what would constitute an answer to your question. If you want something like primitive recursive functions that would capture $P$ then the answer is yes. Replace the recursion with bounded recursion on notation and it will capture exactly function in $P$.

Comment: Each language is defined by its own grammar. You seem to be asking for a meta-grammar that defines the grammars of the languages in P, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Here is [what grammar means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). In formal languages a grammar generate a language, not a class of languages. But you are asking for *a* grammar for a *class of languages* ($P$) not just one language. I am guessing that you mean something like a syntax for a programming language, something like say C++. (btw, please read [the FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) if you haven't yet.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have notions of linear logic, you might want to have a look at the article *Soft Linear Logic and Polynomial Time* [1] that describes a variant of linear logic (some of the deduction rules have been modified) whose formulas are only provable by proof that are polynomial-time algorithm.

[1] http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.6.1196

**Abstract:** We present a subsystem of second order Linear Logic with restricted rules for exponentials so that proofs correspond to polynomial time algorithms, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not talking about "a grammar", but rather a grammar formalism, or class of grammars, then this might be useful: **the class of languages generated by Range Concatenation Grammars (RCG) is exactly PTIME** (for a proof, see [Bertsch and Nederhof](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CBYQFjAAOAo&url=ftp://ftp.dfki.uni-sb.de/papers/local/nederhof01c.ps.gz&rct=j&q=range%20concatenation%20grammars%20%22ptime%22&ei=zZbZTdDKBYyZOqLyxOEP&usg=AFQjCNGfY3BbaLPjJjTrxNitJ0o7BW1wQQ); for an introduction to RCG, see various papers by Boullier or the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_concatenation_grammars)).

Comment: This looks very interesting. It seems to me that this construction somewhat blurs the difference between a syntactic method to define a language and a computational model (algorithm) to decide a language.